# Latitudine e longitudine google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I have this code that should show mea Marker in the Google map:

```
enter code here

 var latitudine='<?echo php $_POST['lat']; ?>';
    var longitudine='<?echo php $_POST['lon']; ?>';
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(latitudine,longitudine);
   function initialize()
   {
    var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
  });

 marker.setMap(map);

 // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(15);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

But when i visualize the map, i haven't the marker. In which way can i provide the value "Latitudine" and "Longitudine"?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link that exhibits your problem?  The [posted code](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_noMarker.html) works for me.

Comment: The problem is that when I visualize the map, it is centered in other coordinates.i don't know where is the error. Can anyone figure out where I'm wrong?

Comment: What coordinates are you providing?  Why do you say it is incorrect?  Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link that exhibits your problem? (and say where you expect it to be centered)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the map object here :-

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
  });
```